# 2013 Toyota Highlander Snow Tires/wheels work on 2016 XLE?

Tags: toyota, tires, highlander

We have snow tires/alloy rims for our 2013 Toyota Highlander. We're thinking of upgrading to the 2016 XLE Highlander and am wondering if we can use the same snow tires/wheels.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Both cars share the same bolt pattern and hub size (5 x 114.3" - 60.1mm hub), so the 2013 wheels should bolt onto the 2016 Highlander without issue.

The biggest concern would be that the 2013 Highlander uses 16" wheels vs the 2016's 18" wheels, so the smaller 2013 wheels might not clear the brake calipers on the 2016 Toyota, as they probably increased the rotor size from 2013 to 2016. If the wheels do not fit over the brake calipers, you could install a set of wheel spacers to move the rim further from the hub, allowing it to clear the brakes.

Either way, I would imagine a mid-size SUV like the Highlander will have more than enough clearance in the wheel wells to fit a wide variety of wheel sizes, so that shouldn't be an issue.